# SimpleXml how to correctly set encoding and xmins?

Tags: php, xml, encoding, simplexml

Any ideas on how I can get PHPs SimplXMLElement to kick off with the following?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.2">
```

The main root will then be:

```
<Document></Document>
```

Or do I use simplexml_load_string() to set it up?

Context: I am extending simpleXmlElement to create some kml files.

**EDIT**

Actually, setting the kml xmlns was laughably easy to do:

```
new simpleXMLElement('<kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.2">
<Document></Document></kml>');
```

Just how to set encoding="UTF-8" that is bothering me, seemingly the kml is acceptable without that, but I'd still like to understand how to do it if pos.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

```
new SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'
                          .'<kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.2">'
                          .'<Document></Document></kml>');
```

Comment: Blimey, how simple.  I think I was sloooowly getting there myself.  So the way to think of it is that if you do not implicitly pass an <?xml> string in the constructor, it'll just squirt <?xml version="1.0"> in for you.  Cheers Oz, nice one.  I was under the mistaken belief that I had to somehow mess about with attributes.

Comment: This may have been obvious, but the resulting `$root = new SimpleXML...` element doesn't automatically point to `Document`, so `$root->addChild(...)` would add stuff next to it -- see example http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d33041ddf62087a5f4d7c67eb8c4983d4ef64116

Comment: To explain a little more about @drzaus comment, it doesn't point to `Document` because the root element in the string xml is the element `kml` of which `Document` is a child of.

Comment: Just adding "encoding="UTF-8" doesn't make the resulting XML UTF-8, answer incorrect or title unclear.

Comment: The above didn't work for me, but this did: `$xml = new \SimpleXMLElement('<xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"/>');`